# What is the difference between Texture coordinate node's "Camera" output and Camera data's "View" output?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

According to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html Texture coordinate node's "Camera" output is "Position coordinate in camera space."
Meanwhile according to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/camera_data.html Camera data's "View" is "A camera space vector from the camera to the shading point."?

These two descriptions seem to desribe the same thing.
So what is the difference between Texture coordinate node's "Camera" output and Camera data's "View" output?

Comment: You're right, that sounds like the same thing. But could it possibly be that the aspect ratio of the view/camera plays a role here?

Answer (score 1):

Well spotted.

As far as I can see, *Camera Data* > 'View Vector' is in World Space, not Camera Space.

(Besides being a pure, normalized direction, not a position)

These clusters produce identical results:

[image]

I've reported it as an issue with the docs, we'll see if an editor agrees.